# Keep Bluetooth stream listener from processing the same device multiple times

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am trying to read a stream that has lists of Bluetooth scan results. What I want to do is scan until I find a specific device and process only that device. I am using the `Flutter_Blue_Plus` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus). It exposes a `Stream` of scan results. I listen to the stream and process the list every time it receives new data. However, because it returns a list of all scanned results each time a new device is found, the listener is getting called multiple times before I detect that the correct device has been found and close the stream.

The documentation for `FlutterBluePlus.instance.scanResults` says:

> Returns a stream that is a list of [ScanResult] results while a scan is in progress.
>
> The list emitted is all the scanned results as of the last initiated scan. When a scan is first started, an empty list is emitted. The returned stream is never closed.
>
> One use for [scanResults] is as the stream in a StreamBuilder to display the results of a scan in real time while the scan is in progress.

This code is in a Bloc event handler that is called when a page opens.

```dart
class ProgrammingStatusBloc
    extends Bloc<ProgrammingStatusEvent, ProgrammingStatusState> {
  List<StreamSubscription> streamSubList = [];
  bool continueWriting = true;
  ProgrammingStatusBloc() : super(ProgrammingStatusState.initial()) {
    /// Called when the screen is first loaded
    on<_Started>((event, emit) async {
      continueWriting = true;
      emit(ProgrammingStatusState.initial());
      final isScanningStream =
          FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning.listen((isScanning) {
        if (isScanning && continueWriting) {
          final subscription =
              FlutterBluePlus.instance.scanResults.listen((result) {
            //Using map because it can handle the result list constantly changing length
            result.map((r) async {
              if (r.advertisementData.manufacturerData.containsKey(1234)) {
                //log("Found device with manufacturer data 1234.");
                final mapOfBytes = r.advertisementData.manufacturerData;
                final List<int> listOfBytes = mapOfBytes.entries.first.value;
                final String incomingPartialHexWithoutIdentifier =
                    BitManipulation.listOfBytesToHex(listOfBytes);
                final hexId = event.sensor.id.getOrCrash();
                final idhexString = hexId.toRadixString(16);
                if (!(await FlutterBluePlus.instance.connectedDevices).contains(
                        r.device) && incomingPartialHexWithoutIdentifier.contains(idhexString.toUpperCase())
                    ) {
                  //log("Had not connected to device; connecting now");
                  await r.device.connect(autoConnect: false);
                  add(ProgrammingStatusEvent.connected(true));
                  final mtu = await r.device.mtu.first;
                  await r.device.requestMtu(512);
                  await r.device.discoverServices();
                  final serviceStream = r.device.services.listen(
                      (service) async {
                        log("Length of service list: ${service.length}");
                        for (final s in service) {
                          if (s.uuid.toString() ==
                              "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e") {
                            for (final char in s.characteristics) {
                              const rxChar =
                                  "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
                              const txChar =
                                  "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
                              if (char.uuid.toString() == txChar) {
                                if (continueWriting) {
                                  final List<int> payload = createPayload(event.data);
                                  await char.write(payload);
                                }
                                continueWriting = false;
                                log("Written for char $char");
                                //Disconnect and stop scan after writing (may later be moved to after reading back what was written)
                                r.device.disconnect();
                                FlutterBluePlus.instance.stopScan();
                                break;
                              }
                            }
                            
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      cancelOnError: true,
                      onError: (error) {
                        log("Error listening to device stream: $error");
                      });
                  //Now try to write to the device
                  streamSubList.add(serviceStream);
                } else {
                }
                //return true;
              } else {
                //return false;
              }
            }).toList(); //Otherwise the map() won't get called because it's lazy
          });
          streamSubList.add(subscription);
        } else {
          log("Not scanning.");
          if (continueWriting) {
            log("Started Scan");
            FlutterBluePlus.instance.startScan();
          }
        }
        // }
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
      isScanningStream.cancel();
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried scanning and then reading the result stream after finishing scanning, but then I couldn't discover services correctly for the device. I already checked that the event handler itself is not being called more than once.

How can I prevent the stream listener from being called again before it finishes processing the first set of results?

Comment: "How can I prevent the stream listener from being called again before it finishes processing the first set of results?" - seems that you need `Stream.asyncMap` and not `Stream.map` called with `async` callback

Comment: @pskink How would that keep the listener event handler from being called a second/third/etc time, though?

Comment: it will be called once the callback finishes, try, for example: `Stream.fromIterable([1,3, 5]).asyncMap(mapper).drain();` (note you dont need to call `.toList()` - `Stream.drain` can be used in such cases) with the following callback: `mapper(int i) async {
print('mapper $i enter');
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
print('mapper $i exit');
}` - run it first with `map` and then with `asyncMap`

Comment: @pskink It's not the map I'm trying to keep from being called, really. I'm trying to prevent the entire event handler from being called again: 
```
.listen((result){
  <the map is here, but I don't want the function calling the map to run>
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by moving the `continueWriting` bool from after writing to the device to before.

```dart
if (char.uuid.toString() == txChar) {                    
    if (continueWriting) {
       final List<int> payload = createPayload(event.data);
       await char.write(payload);                
    }
                    
    continueWriting = false;
    log("Written for char $char");      
    //Disconnect and stop scan after writing (may later be moved to after reading back what was written)

    r.device.disconnect();
    FlutterBluePlus.instance.stopScan();
    break;
}
```

was changed to

```dart
if (char.uuid.toString() == txChar) {                    
    if (continueWriting) {
       continueWriting = false;
       final List<int> payload = createPayload(event.data);
       await char.write(payload);                
    }
                    
    log("Written for char $char");      
    //Disconnect and stop scan after writing (may later be moved to after reading back what was written)

    r.device.disconnect();
    FlutterBluePlus.instance.stopScan();
    break;
}
```

This meant the flag was set quickly enough to prevent other event handlers from writing to the device.